Generating animations in real time
For enemies in a video game is there a way to change / generate an animation based off predefined code to work in any given environment.
An example could be a giant spider walking over rough terrain, or other stuff.
I intend to use this to use different attacks depending on where the user is (ie. hitting a large spider arm around a stone beam)
Generally looking for the name of what I am explaining so I can research it.

I remember seeing a youtube video featuring this animation style, but am unable to find it. It was about creating contraptions to play as and defeating enemy contraptions to gain parts.

This is called procedural animation, because the pose data is computed via some procedure at runtime, rather than just looked up/interpolated from a pre-baked animation timeline.
Some examples of pure procedural animation in various forms:

Animation Bootcamp: An Indie Approach to Procedural Animation (synthesizing biped animation in Overgrowth)
This spider can climb anywhere! (placing footsteps and animating legs to crawl over arbitrary terrain)
Animating with Math (using vertex shaders to add complex motion to props — this is also how schools of fish are animated in Abzu)
Giving personality to procedural animations with math (layering dynamics like anticipation and bounce to make computed animations look less stiff/robotic)
A little experiment I made for a 3-day game jam, building a procedural dance in response to player input.

This can also be mixed with conventional, pre-authored animations in various ways:

Using weighted/masked blends between authored poses / animations, like having "aim forward, up, up-right, right" etc. poses and blending between them to match the player's input / NPC action.
Inverse kinematics (IK), where we calculate and override a chain of joint angles in an animation to, e.g. keep feet planted on an uneven surface, or keep a hand correctly gripping a held object.
Layering "additive animations" on top of simple walk/idle loops, to make them look less repetitive and more natural.
Dynamically adding leans, "smear frame" distortion, or squash & stretch scaling over-top of a conventional skeletal animation to make it look more cartoony and responsive to what's happening in the game.


Any chance that you have some more links on this, such as scholar articles or things that go into greater depths on how everything works and possibilities of change in relation to IK or Procedural Animation as a whole?

Just using the search term "procedural animation" will turn up a bunch of hits. I can try to curate some if you're looking to animate something specific or need help with a specific technique, but for a general survey, your search will turn up the same results as mine.
